# Adding units to heatmap annotation in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to show a table of percentages as a heatmap in Seaborn:

```
sns.heatmap(S, annot=True, fmt=".1f", linewidths=1.0, square=1)
```

However, I'd like the percent sign to appear after each number in the heatmap annotations. The `fmt` flag only seems to accept number format specifiers. Is there a way to do this either within Seaborn or with some matplotlib tweaking?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to iterate over all text values of a heatmap and add % sign:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

sns.set()
fig, ax0 = plt.subplots(1,1)
data = np.array([[10.01,20.20],[-0.23,0.],[23.1049,-100.000000]])
ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, fmt = '.1f', square=1, linewidth=1.)
for t in ax.texts: t.set_text(t.get_text() + " %")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm looking to add percent signs to the annotations (e.g. 0.23% in your figure), not to the colorbar.

Comment: Converting '.1f' to '.1%' solved the problem for me.

Comment: It is nice solution, but it will be better to change the label  to percent as well.

Comment: Do you know how to express in millions. e.g. 500k shows up as 0.5m

Answer (score 29):

Replace the ".1f" to ".1%".  And it should solve your problem.

```
sns.heatmap(S, annot=True, fmt=".1%", linewidths=1.0, square=1)
```

Comment: Then the colormap will be from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 100.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for on google!

Comment: @ilija139 You are right. Please see my answer that addresses the colorbar. p

Answer (score 2):

You will have to both adjust the format of your 'annotations' using the `fmt` parameter AND the 'colorbar' using `cbar_kws`.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
fmt = lambda x,pos:'{:.0%}'.format(x)
hm = sns.heatmap(data=S, annot=True, ax=ax1, fmt='.1%', cbar_kws={'format': FuncFormatter(fmt)})
```

For reference check this [seaborn issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/917).