# Adding specific grid cells in a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d")
```

Apart from the annotation added in the code above, I want to annotate specific grid cells in this heatmap. e.g. add a string `hello` in the second row third column. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/73419138/7758804

Comment: Create a custom dataframe `annot` (from pivoted `flights`) with all of the desired string annotations, and pass it to the `annot=` parameter.